Excel vba change event return to target cell
I have a worksheet which has this change event code imbedded within it. Essentially when the change event is triggered it jumps back to the declared range, places the old and new data in arrays and places them into another sheet which i use to track the changes made to the document.
The issue I'm having is with the 'application.undo' section. The code does this so excel can retireve the data from the cell linked to the change event range however I'd like the code to select the last target cell the user selected rather than the offset option. However i believe the 'application.undo' is making this impossible as it removes that last target action.
Can anyone assist?
    Dim RangeValues As Variant, E As Long, boolOne As Boolean, TgValue 
 Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = Worksheets("Change Log")
 Dim UN As String: UN = Application.UserName
 

 If sh.Range("A1") = "" Then sh.Range("A1").Resize(1, 8) = _
                                     Array("Time", "User Name", "Changed cell", "Role", "From", "To", "Supplier", "Sheet Name")


''''''Name Change
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False                                     
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 If Not Intersect(Target, Union(RNG1, RNG2, RNG3, RNG4, RNG5, RNG6, RNG7, RNG8, RNG9, RNG10, RNG11, RNG12, RNG13, RNG14, RNG15, RNG16, RNG17, RNG18, RNG19, RNG20, RNG21, RNG22, RNG23, RNG24, RNG25, RNG26, RNG27, RNG28, RNG29, RNG30)) Is Nothing Then
 If Target.Cells.count > 1 Then
    TgValue = extractData(Target)
 Else
    TgValue = Array(Array(Target.Value, Target.Address(0, 0)))  'put the target range in an array (or as a string for 

a single cell)
    boolOne = True
 End If
 Application.EnableEvents = False                                
     Application.Undo
     RangeValues = extractData(Target)                           
     putDataBack TgValue, ActiveSheet                            
        If boolOne Then Target.Offset(, 1).Select
 Application.EnableEvents = True


 For E = 0 To UBound(RangeValues)
    If RangeValues(E)(0) <> TgValue(E)(0) Then
        sh.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 8).Value = _
                Array(Now, UN, RangeValues(E)(1), Target.Offset(E, -2).Cells(1).Value, RangeValues(E)(0), TgValue(E)(0), Target.Offset(E, 2).Cells(1).Value, Target.Parent.Name)
    End If
 Next E
End If
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub putDataBack(arr, sh As Worksheet)
    Dim i As Long, arrInt, El
    For Each El In arr
        sh.Range(El(1)).Value = El(0)
    Next
End Sub


Function extractData(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim a As Range, arr, count As Long, i As Long
    ReDim arr(rng.Cells.count - 1)
    For Each a In rng.Areas 'creating a jagged array containing the values and the cells address
            For i = 1 To a.Cells.count
                arr(count) = Array(a.Cells(i).Value, a.Cells(i).Address(0, 0)): count = count + 1
            Next
    Next
    extractData = arr
End Function

 


Not enough time to attentive look through the event code, but what about ending it with Target.Select...?

Before your event handler does anything, store the current Selection so you can restore it when done.
